# element.isDisplayed() is returning false where as element is displayed on the screen

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`element.isDisplayed()` is returning false where as element is displayed on the screen, because of which i am  unable to click on the element. Tried using below code, but no luck

```
                    Actions cursor = new Actions(driver);
                    cursor.moveToElement(element);
                    cursor.click(element).build().perform();
```

also used below code :

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click;", element);
```

which again is not working.

HTML

```
<TD id=PanelTable class=menulevel1norm onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onclick="JAVASCRIPT CODE">&nbsp;Order&nbsp;</TD>
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; POSITION: absolute; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; VISIBILITY: hidden; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" name="actiondiv">
    <DIV myonclick="SOME JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE">Order Console</DIV>
    <DIV myonclick="SOME JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE">Order Release</DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Can you add some relevant HTML?

Comment: <TD id=PanelTable class=menulevel1norm onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onclick="JAVASCRIPT CODE">&nbsp;Order&nbsp; </TD>

 <DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; POSITION: absolute; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; VISIBILITY: hidden; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" name="actiondiv">
 <DIV myonclick="SOME JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE">Order Console </DIV>
 <DIV myonclick="SOME JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE">Order Release </DIV>
 </DIV>

Comment: byclicking on the top TD below DIV will be visible like a bootstrap dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you are doing and which is wrong is executing this JavaScript:

```
arguments[0].click;
```

It won't raise an error as the `.click` field exists. (So long as what you pass to `.executeScript` is a `WebElement` instance.) However, `.click` is a method and you are not calling it. You'd need:

```
arguments[0].click();
```

Comment: No luck even with .click();